# How to use MLE method for non-distribution function?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I understand that maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) method is normally used with distribution function. However is there anyway around I can do to use MLE for a function which is not distribution function? Is there any example for this as well that I can see?